# Why Xcode 9 change my outlet unsafe_unretained by default

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I control-drag outlet from xib, I got unsafe_unretained property by default. I'm using Xcode 9.1. The following code is what it looks like.

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *shIndexLabel;
```

Answer (score 1):

> **__unsafe_unretained** specifies a reference that does not keep the referenced object alive and is not set to nil when there are no strong
>   references to the object. If the object it references is deallocated,
>   the pointer is left dangling.

Above excerpt from Apple docs. So answering your question **WHY**?

> It is not possible for the Swift compiler to know if these references
>   are really intended to be strong (+1) or unretained (+0)

This change involved with respect to the swift compiler. They made **__unsafe_unretained** by default.

Comment: Thanks for your professional answer! One more question, did `weak` do the same thing to swift compiler?

Comment: Please accept this answer in case it clarified your doubt. So that it will be useful to some other person having the same doubt as you.

Comment: Swift compiler knows weak(+0) at least. Apple changed it to __unsafe_unretained to indicate outlets will be left dangling. I don't understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's a bug of Xcode. It seems `unsafe_unretained` will appear when project didn't complete indexing. So we should change it to `weak` manually.